# Including installers in Azure cloudservice bloats resulting package

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a standard azure webrole that requires some 3rd party software to be installed on the cloud service.  The webrole itself is very basic. The 3rd party software has a few prerequisites, so everything is being included in the role's content (a total of 5 MSI files) and is installed via a an elevated startup task.

The software is installing successfully and everything's working, but including these MSIs as content for the webrole results in an 80MB *.cspkg file.

Excluding the installers yields a package size of 10MB. The total size of all the 5 MSI files is 20.5MB.  I don't understand why including 20MB of installers  results in an 80MB cloud service package.

I think the packaging process might be attempting to compress the files (unintentionally increasing the payload).  Is what I'm seeing normal?  Or is there any way of reducing the resulting package when installers are included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package for WebRoles is usually bigger then one for worker roles because your role content is included twice! Once is `approot` folder and once in `sites\0\` folder.

As a second thought of yours - compressing. This is true. Azure package is just a regular zip file. You can safely rename `yourpackage.cspkg` to `yourpackage.zip` and browse the content.

However your strategy for keeping installation files in package is not effective in its roots. What I will suggest is that you put your 3rd party installer in a blob storage. Then first download it and then install it. For downloading the content you can use various techniques. From [PowerShell](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2006-how-to-download-a-file-from-the-internet-with-windows-powershell/) to [Azure Bootstrapper](http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/) and probably many more.

Having your (all and any of them) 3rd party installers in a Blob storage is a recommended best practice for designing applications for Windows Azure.

As to the question why your Web Application is copied twice in the Azure Deployment package - it has its roots in the times where [Windows Azure Web Role was using IIS Hostable Web Core and not full IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx). And is probably still there for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that the *.cspkg files were compressed but couldn't account for what seemed as exponential growth. Obvious now, considering the installers are included twice! Storing the installers in blob storage was going to be my next step; that's its best practice is a huge bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I found if you add the **msi** to the \bin folder of the Azure project it doesn't copy multiple times, in this style:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet

Using Visual Studio 2017, Azure SDK 2.9, Build Engine version 14.0.27530.0